A question about eigenvalues/eigenvectors in the Page 291 of Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra 5th.
It writes

$P=\begin{bmatrix}0.5&0.5\\0.5&0.5\end{bmatrix}$

Markov matrix: Each column of P adds to 1, so $\lambda=1$ is an eigenvalue.
P is singular, so $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue.
P is symmetric, so its eigenvectors (1,1) and (1,-1) are perpendicular.


I can only understand the second proposition. Could you please help explain the first and third propositions? Thank you very much!

Proposition 1 is a well-known consequence of the Brouwer fixed point theorem - a continuous map taking a compact convex set to itself has a fixed point. Markov/Stochastic matrices (those matrices with positive elements and whose columns sum to 1) map probability vectors to probability vectors. The space of probability vectors is compact and convex so there is a fixed point - an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1.
Proposition 3 is just the spectral theorem (or eigendecomposition) for real symmetric matrices.
